# groupby and sum to calculate into new column and organized hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by, sum

I'm trying to groupby my dataframe into a tree format so that it sorts down in a hierarchical way.
DC being the first column that funnels down into Retailer, Store Count, Product descriptions, case volume and velocity in that order. Summing the retailer column into a new column "StoreCt" that is positioned after "Retailer"

The problem I'm running into is the store counts are being duplicated.

Here is the dataframe I have

| Retailer | DC | Product | Cs | Volume | Velocity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | ABC | bars | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| joe | DFC | drinks1 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| joe | DFC | drinks2 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| randy | ABC | bars | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| peter | DFC | drinks2 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| john | XYZ | drinks | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| joe | XYZ | snacks | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| joe | DFC | bars2 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |

This is the result I want. values in the cs, volume, and velocity columns need to be unchanged

| DC | Retailer | StoreCt | Product | Cs | Volume | Velocity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | joe | 1 | bars | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
|  | randy | 1 | bars | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| DFC | joe | 3 | drinks1 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
|  |  |  | drinks2 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
|  |  |  | bars2 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
|  | peter | 1 | drinks2 | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
| XYZ | joe | 1 | snacks | Cs | Cost | Velocity |
|  | john | 1 | drinks | Cs | Cost | Velocity |

this is my code to get the store count, but i can't figure out how to add it into the dataframe without duplicating the values

```
store_count = df.groupby("Retailer").size().to_frame("StoreCt")
store_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to broadcast the result to all rows:

```
df['StoreCt'] = df.groupby(['DC', 'Retailer']).transform('size')
print(df)

# Output:
  Retailer   DC  Product  Cs Volume  Velocity  StoreCt
0      joe  ABC     bars  Cs   Cost  Velocity        1
1      joe  DFC  drinks1  Cs   Cost  Velocity        3
2      joe  DFC  drinks2  Cs   Cost  Velocity        3
3    randy  ABC     bars  Cs   Cost  Velocity        1
4    peter  DFC  drinks2  Cs   Cost  Velocity        1
5     john  XYZ   drinks  Cs   Cost  Velocity        1
6      joe  XYZ   snacks  Cs   Cost  Velocity        1
7      joe  DFC    bars2  Cs   Cost  Velocity        3
```

To get the output, you can reorder the columns:

```
cols = ['DC', 'Retailer', 'StoreCt', 'Product', 'Cs', 'Volume', 'Velocity']
df = df[cols].sort_values(['DC', 'Retailer'], ignore_index=True)
print(df)

# Output
    DC Retailer  StoreCt  Product  Cs Volume  Velocity
0  ABC      joe        1     bars  Cs   Cost  Velocity
1  ABC    randy        1     bars  Cs   Cost  Velocity
2  DFC      joe        3  drinks1  Cs   Cost  Velocity
3  DFC      joe        3  drinks2  Cs   Cost  Velocity
4  DFC      joe        3    bars2  Cs   Cost  Velocity
5  DFC    peter        1  drinks2  Cs   Cost  Velocity
6  XYZ      joe        1   snacks  Cs   Cost  Velocity
7  XYZ     john        1   drinks  Cs   Cost  Velocity
```

Comment: You can also reorder the columns and sort ;)

Comment: I'm receiving this error when using transform. Any ideas? TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types

Comment: Does it work if you use `df.groupby(['DC', 'Retailer'])['DC'].transform('size')`? You can also replace 'size' by 'count', it should work too.

Comment: Got it! transform decided to work after i added in another column

```df['StoreCt'] = df.groupby(['DC', 'Retailer'])["Retailer"].transform('size')
df```

and then
```cols = ['DC', 'Retailer', 'StoreCt', 'Product', 'Cs', 'Volume', 'Velocity']
df = df[cols].sort_values(['DC', 'Retailer'], ignore_index=True)
df.head()```

lastly
```sales_by_dc = df.groupby(["DC", "Retailer", "StoreCt", "Product"]).sum()
sales_by_dc```
Thank you everyone!